# Data-Mapper Under passenger and ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

My sinatra app is showing an error when declaring required on fields using datamapper running on passenger and ruby 1.8

error:  undefined local variable or method `required' for Person:Class

```
class Person
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :salutation, String 
property :first_name, String , required => true 
property :last_name, String , required => true 
property :email, String , required => true, :format => :email_address 
property :phone, String , required => true
property :dob, String 
property :no_of_guests, String , required => true
property :attending, String, required => true

property :created_at, DateTime
end
```

Is this an issue with datamapper and ruby 1.8, or passenger or the way I'm decalring the required attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`required`has to be a symbol (`:required`):

```
class Person
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :salutation, String 
property :first_name, String , :required => true 
property :last_name, String , :required => true 
property :email, String , :required => true, :format => :email_address 
property :phone, String , :required => true
property :dob, String 
property :no_of_guests, String , :required => true
property :attending, String, :required => true

property :created_at, DateTime
end
```

Comment: oh dear.  Thank you.  i also got round it doing this: validates_presence_of :email,  :last_name, :phone etc

Comment: it is a common mistake and it can take hours to figure that out if you're not used to that. Use the #datamapper channel on freenode to get faster answers.